# Document Similarity Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am trying to get related documents for a list of 10,000 documents from the same set of 10,000 docs. I am using two algorithms for testing: gensim lsi and gensim similarity. Both give terrible results. How can I improve it?

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

def cleanword(word):
    return re.sub(r'\W+', '', word).strip()

def create_corpus(documents):

    # remove common words and tokenize
    stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
    stoplist.append('')
    texts = [[cleanword(word) for word in document.lower().split() if cleanword(word) not in stoplist]
             for document in documents]

    # remove words that appear only once
    all_tokens = sum(texts, [])
    tokens_once = set(word for word in set(all_tokens) if all_tokens.count(word) == 1)

    texts = [[word for word in text if word not in tokens_once] for text in texts]

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
    corp = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

def create_lsi(documents):

    corp = create_corpus(documents)
    # extract 400 LSI topics; use the default one-pass algorithm
    lsi = models.lsimodel.LsiModel(corpus=corp, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=400)
    # print the most contributing words (both positively and negatively) for each of the first ten topics
    lsi.print_topics(10)

def create_sim_index(documents):
    corp = create_corpus(documents)
    index = similarities.Similarity('/tmp/tst', corp, num_features=12)
    return index
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't expect much from purely unsupervised statistical methods, such as LSI or LDA. Try `tf-idf`, cosine similarity, stronger stopwords list,  other clustering methods (e.g. k-means)

Comment: Nah, the approach is fine. It's just the hotch-potch of copypasted code that causes trouble here @alvas :)

Comment: @Radim can gensim be used with Solr/ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not using `create_lsi()` at all? You just print the created LSI model, then forget it.

And where does the number `12` in `num_features=12` come from? It should be either `num_features=len(dictionary)` for BOW vectors, or `num_features=lsi.num_topics` for LSI vectors.

Add TF-IDF transformation before LSI.

Check out the gensim tutorial at http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html, it goes over these steps in more detail & with comments.

Answer (score 0):

LSI is used for large corpus of text data. We can form a matrix with relevant terms in reduced space using singular value decomposition. Here in gensim package, you can get the top semantically similar terms by returning only top n terms.

lsimodel.print_topic(10, topn=5)
where 10 is number of topics and 5 shows top five terms from each topics.

Thereby you can reduce irrelevant terms.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use other machine learning algorithms like : clustering (k-means) with cosine similarity for example